# Menu for pictures average program

Tags: python

I made a little script that takes images and averages / aligns them.

The script grew and now I have different options bound to the program, it can calculate the average for RGB or gray scale pictures and can create test data set to check if it works on different machines.

At the beginning I define the help message, yet isn't there a better way to store it?

```
def main(argv):
    help_message  = "---------------- HELP ----------------\n"
    help_message += "Usage:\n"
    help_message += "pythong main_avg.py -d path/to/folder/ -cd -cdrgb -avg -avgrgb -graph\n"
    help_message += "  -d | --directory: path to any directory, the program will generate the dataset, or calculate the average in the folder.\n"
    help_message += "  -cd: creates gray scale dataset.\n"
    help_message += "  -cdrgb: creates rgb scale dataset.\n"
    help_message += "  -avg: calculates the alignment and average of the picture in greyscale mode.\n"
    help_message += "  -avgrgb: calculates and outputs a rgb average, needs the data from -avg.\n"
    help_message += "  -graph: calculates and outputs the movement and angles graphs, needs the data from -avg.\n"
    help_message += "  -s: sound at the end of process.\n"    
    help_message += "  -h, --help: prints this.\n"
```

Then I print the starting script, just because

```
    path, name, ext = get_pathname(argv[0])
    print("Script:", name + ext, "started")
```

Then I process the arguments

```
    # get the arguments
    opts = argv[1:]

    folder = ""
    create_dataset = False
    create_rgb_dataset = False
    avgerage_gray = False
    average_rgb = False
    produce_graphs = False
    sound_of_silence = False


    if len(opts) == 1 and opts in ('-h', '--help'):
        print(help_message)
    else:
        nopt = 0
        while nopt < len(opts):
            opt = opts[nopt]
            if opt in ("-d", "--directory"):
                try:
                    nopt += 1 
                    folder = opts[nopt]
                except IndexError:
                    pass
            if opt == "-cd":
                create_dataset = True
            if opt == "-cdrgb":
                create_rgb_dataset = True
            if opt == "-avg":
                avgerage_gray = True
            if opt == "-avgrgb":
                average_rgb = True
            if opt == "-graph":
                produce_graphs = True
            if opt == "-s":
                sound_of_silence = True
            nopt += 1
```

The program checks if one option is chosen, and if so it start the subroutine.

```
    inopt = [create_dataset, create_rgb_dataset, avgerage_gray, average_rgb, produce_graphs]

    if isdir(folder):
        if all(opt == False for opt in inopt):
            print("No options chosen")
            print("")
            print(help_message)
        if create_dataset:
            run_create_test_dataset(folder)

        if create_rgb_dataset:
            run_create_rgb_dataset(folder)

        if avgerage_gray:
            run_average_gray(folder)

        if average_rgb:
            run_average_rgb(folder)

        if produce_graphs:
            run_produce_graphs(folder)   

        if sound_of_silence:
            import winsound
            Freq = 2500 # Set Frequency To 2500 Hertz
            Dur = 1000 # Set Duration To 1000 ms == 1 second
            winsound.Beep(Freq,Dur)            
    else:
        print("-d option is not a folder")
        print("")
        print(help_message)
```

Is the first time I build a argumented main, so I would love any suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally would suggest using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#module-argparse).
To make a simple one would be fairly easy, and could only require [`add_argument`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument).
You only really need to know:

- The first to arguments store a single letter argument such as `-d`, and a long version such as `--directory`.
- It takes an argument of `action='store_true'` to make the variable a flag.
- It takes `help` as the help text.

And so you could use:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='main avg')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--directory',
                    help='path to any directory, the program will generate the dataset, or calculate the average in the folder.')
parser.add_argument('--cd', action='store_true',
                    help='creates gray scale dataset.')
parser.add_argument('--cdrgb', action='store_true',
                    help='creates rgb scale dataset.')
parser.add_argument('--avg', action='store_true',
                    help='calculates the alignment and average of the picture in greyscale mode.')
parser.add_argument('--avgrgb', action='store_true',
                    help='calculates and outputs a rgb average, needs the data from -avg.')
parser.add_argument('--graph', action='store_true',
                    help='calculates and outputs the movement and angles graphs, needs the data from -avg.')
parser.add_argument('-s', action='store_true',
                    help='sound at the end of process.')

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.cd:
    run_create_test_dataset(args.directory)
elif args.cdrgb:
    run_create_rgb_dataset(args.directory)
...
else:
    print('No options chosen')
```

After this, you may want to look into [`add_mutually_exclusive_group`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion), if they're mutually exclusive.

Comment: I tried to use argparse, but I couldn't manage to make it with multiple letters arguments, so at the end I decided to reinvent the will in fact that is why you can see opt arg, I copied the synthax from there. But thx for the new solution!!

Comment: @Pella86 what do you mean by that... If I understand you correctly I've done the same thing multiple times in `argparse` and I believe the python documentation shows how to do this.

Comment: Tbh I dont know exactly what module I used, and maybe I just didn't understand the tutorial well. I don't have the old version but I wrote it quite some times.

Comment: @Pella86 What you may have done was used a single `-` for multi-letter arguments - the `--` prefix is standard for that as `-abcde` is equivalent to `-a -b -c -d -e` for brevity's sake.

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use the built-in [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library. Less code, more standard. It also generates the `-h` help text for you automatically.

Another possibility is to use [`docopt`](http://docopt.org).  There, you just write the docstring for the program, and the library magically generates the command-line parsing code for you.

Answer (score 3):

The very first thing that I noticed was that you've seriously **reinvented the wheel** by trying to manually handling command-line arguments.

In Python, there is a built-in [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) that you can use to parse command-line arguments. It would make the code much shorter, more readable and, as a bonus, you'll get an *auto-generated help message*.

You can create custom types, custom actions and much more - there is even a [convenient way to parse the directory path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11415570/771848).

And, here is a very nice way to call different functions based on a presence of a command-line argument:

- [Call function based on argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27529806/771848)

---

I've also heard a lot of awesome things about the [`click` library](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) - definitely check it out.